# Форматирование числа

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress. Есть код `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-house_price', true) ?> руб.`, выводящий цену объекта. Как с помощью `number_format()` отформатировать число? 2 знака после запятой и отделение тысяч пробелом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php echo number_format(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-house_price', true), 2, ',', ' '); ?> руб.
```

Comment: была мысль, что такая запись может сработать, но почему-то я подумал, что это было бы слишком просто. Сработало, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте, например, вот так:

```
$num = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');   // 1 234,56
```

Comment: логически я понимаю, что и как попробовать. У меня с синтаксисом проблемы,  не могли бы вы привести написать полный код?